Logic App :: Move files form AWS S3 to Blob Storage
I'm trying to create a perfect directional sync between AWS S3 and Azure Blob Storage.
The actions go like this:

Every 5 minutes check if an object is updated in AWS S3 bucket:



If so take the content of that object and copy it to the target blob:


But when I run it it basically start trigging a new action every 5 minutes but the previous action never ends.
So I had to manually cancel all activities:

Where am I wrong?
Is that because the Copy blob (v2) provides copy only between Azure Bob storages and not between AWS and Azure?
UPDATE: I see where the problem is, it's waiting for an object to be updated on S3:

and keeps going on and on.

Do you have the option for a "Create" blob task, instead of copy blob?

yes, why should I use that?

Yeah. Your S3 action is already grabbing the content of the Blob, so it just needs to be written to Azure blob. The input blob data should be the S3 task output.

Hello @ArchitectJamie, unfortunately even if I use Create blob (v2) the Logic App just keeps going on and on with no end

Hello @ArchitectJamie, I see where the problem is. So in this case the second step should be trigged just once and Logic App should keep seeking for changes. That is going to cost a lot...

Yeah. You're better off using a HTTP trigger in your Logic App, and using event notifications in S3 to trigger the webhook, I should think.

@ArchitectJamie, I found a nearly out-of-the-box solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-migration-guidance-s3-azure-storage#delta-data-migration. If your data in AWS S3 isn't time partitioned, ADF can identify new or changed files by their LastModifiedDate. The way it works is that ADF will scan all the files from AWS S3, and only copy the new and updated file whose last modified timestamp is greater than a certain value.

@ArchitectJamie, do you think I can use LastModifiedDate in Logic App?

I wouldn't use that. Yes, you could use a "List objects" action, then loop through the results and use a "Get object metadata" action for the last modified date. However, this action results in a HTTP HEAD request for every blob, and is charged by Amazon similar to a GET request, even though the blob data is not being retrieved. I can post an answer with steps to use event driven invocation of the logic app via webhook?

Yes, please, that would be great @ArchitectJamie. So you mean that the cost of the HTTP HEAD request will always be there. ADF or Logic App. For both?

If you are not concerned with the cost per every Head request, you can go ahead with the approach using Get object metadata action as suggested by @Architect Jamie in the comments.

So you mean that the cost of the HTTP HEAD request will always be there. ADF or Logic App. For both?

In ADF, you can try copy activity as a workaround for this. You can copy all of your files to the target using copy activity and here there will be no HTTP HEAD request for each file.
Create Binary datasets for both AWS and Blob locations. Give these as source and sink of the copy activity.
Give the expression @addMinutes(utcnow(),-<your_reccurence_time_in_minutes>) to Start time and @utcnow() to End Time as below.

Here, the above wild card path only copies the files inside inputdata/<any_folder/> recursively. If you want to copy the files inside the root container, then remove the wild card file path in the folder name and kept only in the file name. It means, you need to use another copy activity after this with same filter dates for the files inside root container.
In the sink, give the Blob binary dataset.

You can schedule this pipeline using Schedule trigger in the ADF. Give your time in the trigger and publish the changes.

This pipeline will run for every 5 minutes, and it will copy the files modified in the last 5 minutes to the destination.
